# Laravel change URL language dynamically with the current language

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a project with two languages and I change the language by route

```
Route::get('/language/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    app()->setLocale($locale);
    session()->put('locale', $locale);

    return redirect()->back();
});
```

and this is the button switcher

```
<li class="nav-item lang-nav fw-bold ms-1 me-md-5">
    @if ($current_locale == $arabic_locale)
        <a class="nav-link text-mine-blue text-center" href="language/{{ $english_locale }}">
            English
        </a>
    @endif
    @if ($current_locale == $english_locale)
        <a class="nav-link text-mine-blue text-center" href="language/{{ $arabic_locale }}">
            عربي
        </a>
    @endif
</li>
```

and I need to change my URLs language two when changing languages
for example if the URL is mywebsite/articles and the user changed the language, I need to change '/articles' to the other language, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need something like this:
https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization